# Access UITextField inside a CollectionView Footer

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with a custom footer I wrote:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{
    FooterViewController *footer = (FooterViewController*)[collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionViewFooter" forIndexPath:indexPath];

```
return footer;
```

}

The footer has a UITextField inside of it. 
How can I access it's value from the CollectionViewViewController?